# Django what changes require a server restart

Tags: django, restart, reboot

I know Django does have some ability to accept changes without restarting the server, but then there are situations where a change requires a reboot.

Is there any definitive rules as to what changes require a reboot (or what changes don't).

Answer (score 2):

I know changes to settings.py will require the webserver restart to take effect.

Answer (score -2):

A restart/reload of your webserver is only required if you change any of your Python source files, or your server configuration.